# How to upload an app bundle (.aab) onto my private Nexus repository?

Tags: android, curl, gitlab-ci, nexus3

I have a GitLab CI pipeline that builds an Ionic app and then uploads it onto my Nexus Maven repository. I generate both an apk and an aab file that I upload via cURL. However, even though the APK file is properly pushed to the repo, the AAB file is nowhere to be found.

**.gitlab-ci.yml file:**

```yaml
build-apk:
  stage: build
  tags: [docker]
  script:
    - rm package-lock.json
    - npm install -g ionic@5.4.15 cordova@9.0.0
    - npm run build:android:$STAGE
    - cd platforms/android
    - ./gradlew bundleRelease
    - cd ../..
    - echo $ANDROID_DEBUG_KEYSTORE | base64 --decode > key.keystore
    - mv platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk app-release.apk
    - mv platforms/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab $CI_PROJECT_NAME.aab
    - jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore key.keystore -storepass "$ANDROID_DEBUG_PASSPHRASE" app-release.apk <keyName>
    - jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore key.keystore -storepass "$ANDROID_DEBUG_PASSPHRASE" $CI_PROJECT_NAME.aab <keyName>
    - $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools/30.0.2/zipalign 4 app-release.apk $CI_PROJECT_NAME.apk

deploy-mobile:
  stage: deploy
  tags: [shell]
  cache: {}
  script:
    - curl -u $NEXUS_USER:$NEXUS_PWD -v --upload-file $CI_PROJECT_NAME.aab $NEXUS_MAVEN/$CI_PROJECT_NAME/$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$TAG.aab
    - curl -u $NEXUS_USER:$NEXUS_PWD -v --upload-file $CI_PROJECT_NAME.apk $NEXUS_MAVEN/$CI_PROJECT_NAME/$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$TAG.apk
  dependencies:
    - build-apk
```

When I compare the logs of both commands the only difference I see is that the HTTP answer is **400 bad request** for the aab upload (the apk upload ends with **201 Created**).

Is there any missing information I should add to my cURL command so that the aab file uploads? Am I obliged to use Maven commands to upload an aab file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was coming from my repository's configuration, as it didn't allow uploads of files that do not meet the MIME requirements. Unchecking the option led to a successful upload.
Next step is to figure out whether it is possible with my NXRM version to add [support for custom MIME](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-18846) types, as it does not feel right to disable validation for all files present in the repository.

[image: Repository configuration: the checkbox for validating that all content is of a MIME type appropriate for a Maven repository is checked]